# Get all possible whole numbers from remainder and divider

Tags: number-theory

I am not sure if this is possible.  But I want to know if there is a formula to provide all possible combinations to any $a$ and $b$ in this example or any similar equation where the divider and number after the point is different:

$$a / 5 = b.8 $$
1. A correct answer would be $a=9$, $b=1$.  So $9 / 5 = 1.8$

Is there a calculation or formula to do this thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\frac{a}{5}=b.8$

$\Rightarrow\frac{a}{5}=b + \frac{8}{10}$

$\Rightarrow a=5b+4$

For $b=0,1,2,3...$, you can find corresponding $a$.

Comment: Thanks Wicked-Its looks like I should loop through "b" to provide the "a".  What if "b" was more complicated and I wanted to get a exact number rather than multiple.  Is it possible? example a / 33 =b.333333333333333333333333333333  (I want the 1859 or 56)  This does not seem possible unless I go through 56 attempts at "b" if I'm making sense.

Comment: Every rational number can be written in form $\frac{p}{q}$. Write $b.333$ as $b+\frac{1}{3}$ then you get $a=33b+11$. For given $a$, substitute $a$ in the equation to find $b$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is similar to the following;
$$\frac{a}{5}=b+0.8\\a=5b+4\\a-5b=4$$Like all linear Diophantine equations if you have one solution you can determine all solutions;$$a=9,b=1\\a=9+5k,\ b=1+k\\9+5k-5(1+k)=9-5=4$$You can write it in a nicer way;$$a=4+5k\ \ ,b=k$$

Answer (score 0):

$a/5=b.8\iff$

$a/5=b+0.8\iff$

$a=5b+4$

---

This is a system of $1$ equation in $2$ variables.

So you can choose one variable freely and then compute the other variable.

For example:

- Choose $b=0$ then compute $a=5\cdot0+4=4$
- Choose $b=1$ then compute $a=5\cdot1+4=9$
- Choose $a=19$ then compute $b=(19-4)/5=3$

Comment: Could you explain the use of 4 and how it would change in another equation.  Thanks